# how to create an http reverse proxy and transform the stream with node js

Tags: node.js

I have this working reverse http proxy, but when I add a transform stream and try to pipe it between, nothing seems to be streamed in any direction.

Here's the code:

```
const http = require('http')
const {Transform} = require('stream')

const onRequest = (clientRequest, clientResponse) => {
  const options = {
    hostname: 'test-host',
    port: 80,
    path: clientRequest.url,
    method: clientRequest.method,
    headers: clientRequest.headers
  }

  const proxy = http.request(options, (serverResponse) => {
    serverResponse.pipe(myTransform, {end: true})
    myTransform.pipe(clientResponse, {end: true})
  })

  clientRequest.pipe(myTransform, {end: true})
  myTransform.pipe(proxy, {end: true})
}

const myTransform = new Transform({
  transform(data, encoding, callback) {
    console.log(data)
    callback(null, data)
  }
})

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(5050)
```

Comment: You can't reuse a transform like that. You have to create seperate instances of it for each pipe chain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reduced version of a toy proxy I wrote.

It is able to work with body parser (this version is JSON-only) and transform both the request and the response.

The downside is that it's not very efficient for large requests or responses, because it reads the entire bodies of both the request and response before re-streaming them.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const httpStatus = require('http-status-codes');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("this is where you transform the request");
});

function restreamReq(proxyReq, req, res) {
    if (!req.body) {
        return;
    }
    const contentType = req.get('content-type');
    if (contentType) {
        proxyReq.setHeader('content-type', contentType);
    }
    const contentLength = req.get('content-length');
    if (contentLength) {
        const bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
        const bufferLength = Buffer.byteLength(bodyData);
        if (bufferLength != contentLength) {
            console.warn(`buffer length = ${bufferLength}, content length = ${contentLength}`);
            proxyReq.setHeader('content-length', bufferLength);
        }
        proxyReq.write(bodyData);
    }
}

function restreamRes(proxyRes, req, res) {
    res.status(proxyRes.statusCode);
    for (const key of Object.keys(proxyRes.headers)) {
        let rawValue = proxyRes.headers[key];
        if (!Array.isArray(rawValue)) {
            rawValue = [ rawValue ];
        }
        for (const value of rawValue) {
            res.set(key, value);
        }
    }

    console.log("this is where you transform the response");

    let body = new Buffer('');
    const bodyPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        proxyRes.on('data', (data) => body = Buffer.concat([body, data]));
        proxyRes.on('end', () => resolve());
        proxyRes.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
    });

    bodyPromise
        .then(() => res.end(body))
        .catch(err => res.status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).end());
}

app.use(proxy({
    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
    changeOrigin: true,
    xfwd: false,
    preserveHeaderKeyCase: true,
    selfHandleResponse: true,
    onProxyReq: restreamReq,
    onProxyRes: restreamRes,
}));

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081);

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    server.close();
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: how is that relevant? I'm trying to make my own proxy using streams, if I wanted to use express I would use express

Comment: I thought you're trying to build a reverse proxy that transforms the request and/or response. I did not realize you're looking to use/not use specific modules.